# Twitter share custom text via API via twitter web intent - works only once

Tags: javascript, twitter

I've the following issue: I've build a **quote generator (freecodecamp)** and need to be able to s**hare the quote via twitter**. My approach was via Twitter web intent and the text is the data I receive via the API. It only works once.

HTML:

```
<p>Share the wisdom</p>
      <a class="twitter-share-button" href="#" target="_blank">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
        </span>
      </a>
```

JS:

```
    <script>
  function myFunction() {
      var firstName = document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].value;
      var trumpAPI = "https://api.whatdoestrumpthink.com/api/v1/quotes/personalized?q="+firstName;
      $.getJSON(trumpAPI, function(data, status){
        document.getElementById("trump").innerHTML = data.message;
        $('a[href="#"]').attr("href","https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="+data.message+"&hashtags=trump, quoteoftheday");
      });

      document.getElementById("trump").classList.add("border");

  }
</script>
```

Could it be that the text parameter in the web intent is not dynamic? Any suggestion how to fix this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to guess a little bit because you didn't share your complete functionality, I assume what you do is this:

- You have a button of some sort, clicking which will get another quote.
- Clicking that button calls your `myFunction()`.

If that's correct, then the problem is that your `<a>` element no longer has `href="#"` after the first time the function has run; the `href` is now the intent link. And because of that, `$('a[href="#"]')` no longer selects that link on the second call. If you use `$(".twitter-share-button")` instead, it should work.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer/fix and sorry for not explaining in detail. It was indeed a quick fix. [See it working here](http://onlygreatquotes.com/)